# Cannot convert type in Iterable implementation in Java

Tags: java, types, iterator, iterable, mismatch

I have the error:

```
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Card
```

with the following code:

```
Deck Removal
....
for (Card c : Removal)
        d.removeCard(c);
```

This is the iterator method in my deck class:

```
@Override
public Iterator<Card> iterator()
{
    return deck.iterator();
}
```

The underlying structure for the deck is `Vector<Card>`. My iterator is returning type `Card`. Why is it telling me it's `Object` in the for loop?

I can do the following and then the error would go away but that's quite stupid since I'm already supposed to return `Card`s instead of `Objects`.

```
Deck Removal
....
for (Object c : Removal)
        d.removeCard((Card)c);
```

Thanks

Comment: Does Deck implement `Iterable` or `Iterable<Card>`?

Comment: Great! In that case, I'll write my comment as an answer.

Comment: fyi `Vector` is only used in out-of-date educational materials. In the real world, it is a long-abandoned, deprecated and broken class.

Answer (score 3):

In order for the enhanced for loop over `Deck` to return `Card` objects, `Deck` should implement `Iterable<Card>`, instead of just `Iterable`.